# How to send bulk mails using Mandrill in Drupal 7

Tags: configuration, drupal-7, mandrill, bulk, mass-emails

I have an email to be sent to nearly 30,000 users. For this I have installed and configured the Mandrill module for Drupal 7, but I don't know how to start sending emails to my list. Do I need to install any other module?

Comment: What software are you using to send the emails?

Comment: @Simon Hampel, I have installed mandrill module and configured it in my drupal 7 site, I am  stuck at next step on how to start sending bulk emails.

Comment: Where is your list of users? In a database? In a spreadsheet? Somewhere else?

Comment: Users in excel sheet

Comment: Assuming you are sending the same content to all users (perhaps with merge fields to personalise each message), then MailChimp is what you are looking for - as per datashaman's answer. You import your list of users into Mailchimp, create a campaign with the content you want to send them, the tell Mailchimp to send the campaign email to all your users.

Comment: Ya I achieved this through Mailchimp before posting a question here. I want to send bulk email through mandrill. I tried hard but coldnot find a solution. So I cant achieve this through Mandrill?

Comment: Of course, you can send via Mandrill if you want to - but you need to do all the work yourself unlike MailChimp which provides a lot of tools for you. Then you'll need to upload the spreadsheet data to a database, you'll need to write a script which loops through each user and then makes an API call to send the email for each one. Don't forget that Mandrill's sending limits might make the process very slow initially, until your account has "warmed up" and is allowed to send more emails per hour.

Comment: @Simon Hampel, Thanks a lot for your reply, can you guide me to work through mandrill or suggest any source for the same (a step-by-step guide).

Comment: Another issue of using Mandrill to send bulk email is you will not have statistics per campaign. That's one very nice benefit of using Mailchimp for bulk emails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Mandrill's [help](http://help.mandrill.com/entries/27045476-Can-I-upload-my-list-in-Mandrill-):

> Lists cannot be uploaded or stored in Mandrill. Recipient or subscriber lists should be managed in your own database or application. Then, when you're reading to send an email, recipient information is passed to Mandrill in your API request or SMTP message.
>
> Note: If you're looking for a service that provides list-management services as well as the ability to create and track bulk emails, check out [MailChimp](http://www.mailchimp.com/).

Answer (score 1):

1. Import your list of 30k emails to a table in your database.
2. Make another table called sent_emails, where it stores a string for sql, a text column for the html in the email, another text column for a text email, a string column for a subject, the date and time you want the emails to be sent
3. Cron up a bash script that runs every minute and checks for records in the sent_emails table and if so sends the email to the specified list of user ids that gets generated from the sql

Comment: Be sure to handle bounces and spam via the web hooks API to remove from your list. And add a manual unsubscribe too

Answer (score 0):

Yes as @datashaman said, email lists cannot be imported into Mandrill or any other SMTP email gateways like SendGrid, Amazon SES, MailGun, etc.
But you can use 3rd party email clients or email marketing applications, like Sendy to easily integrate Mandrill. You can check Sendy installation services like, [easysendy](https://easysendy.com), which can get all these done for you.
Using Sendy you can manage the list of email subscribers and send emails through the SMTP gateways of your choice.